# I have installed WampServer successfully but when I try to run it, I get this error, how do I fix it?

Tags: database, windows, wamp

This is the error

[image: 1]

I tried reinstallistaling it. It simply doesn't change. I firstly installed it and it worked but then I had to install it again because I couldn't access php. Now it won't start at all.

Comment: Welcome! Can you please first switch your language setting to English to get the error message in English? [Posts on Stack Exchange must be in English](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676/997587). See also: [We require English on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/11107541). Please also read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and remember to **add a transcription** of your image of text as actual text once you get it in English.

Comment: Read the installation instructions. First Install ALL the MSVC Runtimes. You can find them all on the [WAMPServer backup Repo](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en), so much easier to navigate that SourceForge. Look at the bottom of the page

Comment: Thank you for the response! I switched to English but I don't know why the error is still in French. I tried to install it again but it says that it is used by another program even if it is not. I am first time seeing error like this.